GA4 traffic not following same pattern than Search Console?
We recently revamped our website and migrated our CMS from WordPress to Webflow. We use Google Tag Manager (GTM) for all our tags, so during the migration, we simply added GTM to the new website's code.
The domain was supposed to stay the same. However, in the first week after launch, I realized the technical team had mistakenly set the www. version as the default, whereas we’ve always used the non-www version. I noticed this because our Search Console showed no pages or results. Thankfully, this was fixed within the first week, and Search Console started working again.
Now, it’s been about a month and a half since the launch. The results in Search Console have significantly improved compared to the old website (optimizing SEO was one of the goals of the revamp). However, the user numbers in GA4 are not reflecting the same growth.
I understand that impressions and clicks are different from page views, but given the increase in impressions and clicks, I would expect our traffic to at least remain steady, if not improve. Yet GA4 shows a drop.
Does anyone know what might be causing this? I tested in debug mode, and GA4’s page view seems to be firing correctly, at least on the pages I checked.
I’ve attached screenshots for reference.
Thank you!

What specific "results in Search Console" do you mean?  Positions? Clicks?
You haven't attached any screenshots.

Even though you didn't send a screenshot, I have a few assumptions, but first of all, have you tried using GTM debugging? Is there any errors there?
In general, the following could happen: because you changed from the version without www. to the version with www., GA4 data could start to be counted as for the new domain.
Also, due to migration to another platform, there could be a delay in data forwarding, so the data is not immediately reflected in GA reports.

The numbers in GA4 and GSC will typically differ. GSC records all clicks on your site from SERPs. However, if there are issues with loading, the server, or the platform, users may not reach the page. Instead, they may quit or bounce due to slow loading, which won’t be recorded in GA4. There could be other reasons as well, but I believe this discrepancy might be due to the platform migration you recently carried out
